# Create a Lua like JavaScript I18n internationalization

Tags: javascript, lua, internationalization, gettext

In our [Freifunk project gluon](https://github.com/freifunk-gluon/gluon), we use i18n GNU gettext internationalisation in our Lua code (for example for the package `gluon-config-mode-hostname`) we create separate files in a subfolder `i18n`. I want to use this `.po` files to add them in our status-page javascript code:
https://github.com/rubo77/gluon/tree/status-i18n/package/gluon-status-page/i18n

Those contain the translations created by the [msginit](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_chapter/gettext_16.html#msginit-Invocation) program.

How can I use the same i18n files for the javascript based status-page (without jQuery) to translate those strings?

Comment: ajax the file, take lines after the double empty, parse each with a simple `.split()` (and maybe a trim() or slice() to cleanup) into key:value pairs. once you collect all those, you can pass them to your update() function.

Comment: Can you add some examples?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a dirty but verbose way of accomplishing it. Is this what you're looking for?

```js
let url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rubo77/gluon/status-i18n/package/gluon-status-page/i18n/de.po"

fetch(url)
  .then((res) => {
    return res.body.getReader();
  })
  .then((reader) => {
    return reader.read();
  })
  .then((stream) => {
    let decoder = new TextDecoder();
    let body = decoder.decode(stream.value || new Uint8Array);
    return body
  })
  .then((body) => {
    let text = body.replace(/\\n/g, '');
    let lines = text.split('\n');

    console.log(text)
  
    let arr = []
    let obj = {}
  
    for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {

      // key:value pairs
      if (lines[i].indexOf(':') !== -1) {
        let line = lines[i].replace(/"/g, '');
        let pair = line.split(':');
        if (pair.length) {
          obj[pair[0]] = pair[1].trim();
        }
      }


      // msgid
      if (lines[i].indexOf('msgid') !== -1) {
        let msgobj = {};
        let msgid = lines[i].split(' "')[1].replace(/\"/g, '');
        msgobj.msgid = msgid;

        // msgstr
        if (lines[i+1].indexOf('msgstr') !== -1) {
          let msgstr = lines[i+1].split(' "')[1].replace(/\"/g, '');
          msgobj.msgstr = msgstr;
        }

        arr.push(msgobj);
      
      }

    }
  
    arr.push(obj)

  
  document.getElementById('output-source')
    .innerHTML = body
  
  document.getElementById('output-js')
    .innerHTML = JSON.stringify(arr, null, 2);
});
```

```css
.output {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
}
```

```html
<pre id="output-source" class="output"></pre>
<pre id="output-js" class="output"></pre>
```

**NB**: Above example likely only works in Chrome. Here's a [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/nodafebibi/1/edit?js,console,output) that should work in FF.

Comment: This looks great. Although TextDecoder() is not supported by safari.... I will try that later today

Comment: If you're already using jquery in your project you could just AJAX and ditch the fetch/readableStream/decode altogether. Replace first part with this: http://jsbin.com/necihe/2/edit?js,console

Comment: I cannot get this work in firefox 50. can you provide a running example? I also updated my question with the correct translation .po file, we want to use. The eerror I get in the console: `TypeError: res.body is undefined`. this is the example html file I tried: https://github.com/rubo77/gluon/blob/status-i18n/package/gluon-status-page/gettext-example.html

Comment: But the rest of the script seems to work, I changed the reading of the file to some older javascript functions: https://github.com/rubo77/gluon/compare/6334f201ce...f338df6dc9

Comment: And I added i+1 to the msgstr cause it is always in the next line

Comment: But thanks for the hint, with the help of this code I am a lot further in solving the issue. maybe someone can help us developing the rest in https://github.com/freifunk-gluon/gluon/issues/986#issuecomment-270381519

Comment: @rubo77 Here's a [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/nodafebibi/1/edit?js,console,output) that should work in Firefox. I used some ES2015 and Fetch APIs only available to chrome in first iteration.

Comment: That one still doesn't work in Firefox 50.1. I cloned it and added my beginning, that onw works fine: https://jsbin.com/seqidefero/1/edit?html,js,console,output